# SQL Lite group records by substring then take the first one

Tags: sql, sqlite, web-sql

I am in need to generate some data for testing tree structures.
I have extended OrderEntryOrders table with 2 additional columns MasterOrderId (topmost level) and ParentOrderId (master or lower level id).
I was thinking of grouping by record ids on substring of Substr(Id,0,4) to create masterIds and Substr(Id,0,6) for parent Ids, that it would be easyer to see that tree structure got assembled properly.
I got stuck where I need to join table to itself to take TOP 1 record that will be master.

```
SELECT oeo.id, x.str FROM OrderEntryOrders oeo 
JOIN (SELECT Substr(Id,0,6)||'%' as str 
    FROM OrderEntryOrders GROUP BY Substr(Id,0,6)) as x 
ON x.str like oeo.id
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/1ccec/1) as per request.

Comment: You should edit your question to provide sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved myself, and it was in vain as there is no JOIN and UPDATE combination in SQL Lite.

```
select * 
FROM OrderEntryOrders AS ord JOIN (
SELECT oeo.id, x.str FROM OrderEntryOrders AS oeo 
JOIN (SELECT Substr(Id,0,4)||'%' AS str 
    FROM OrderEntryOrders GROUP BY Substr(Id,0,4)) AS x 
ON oeo.id like x.str limit 1
) AS joined 
ON ord.Id like joined.str
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/4d0779/9

Code below in case someone will need to do similar task.

```
onTheMove.openLocalDatabase().transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql("SELECT DISTINCT Substr(Id,0,4)||'%' AS str FROM OrderEntryOrders GROUP BY Substr(Id,0,4)", [], function (transaction, results) {
        console.log('executed');
        var rowsToListDataStructure = function (results) {
            var array = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                array.push(results.rows.item(i));
            }

            return array;
        }
        $.each(rowsToListDataStructure(results), function (i, item) {
            console.log("SELECT ID FROM OrderEntryOrders WHERE ID LIKE '" + item.str + "' LIMIT 1");
            transaction.executeSql("SELECT ID FROM OrderEntryOrders WHERE ID LIKE '" + item.str + "' LIMIT 1", [], function (tra, res) {
                console.log(res.rows.item(0));
                console.log("UPDATE OrderEntryOrders SET MasterOrderId ='" + res.rows.item(0).Id + "' WHERE ID LIKE '" + item.str + "'");
                tra.executeSql("UPDATE OrderEntryOrders SET MasterOrderId ='" + res.rows.item(0).Id + "' WHERE ID LIKE '" + item.str + "'", [],
                    function () {
                        console.log('update success')
                    },
                    function () {
                        console.log('update fail');
                    });
            }, function () {
                console.log('fail');
            })
        })
    })
});
```